Why are weights linear functionals?
This is likely a silly question. Why are generalized eigenvalues necessarily linear functionals? For example given a finite-dimensional representation $(\phi, V)$ of a finite-dimensional, complex, semi-simple Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ with a fixed Cartan subalgebra $\mathfrak{h} \subseteq \mathfrak{g}$, I know that $\lambda \in \mathfrak{h}^*$ is called a weight provided that the space $V_{\lambda} = \{v \in V : \phi(h)v = \lambda(h)(v) \text{ for all } h \in \mathfrak{h}\}$ is non-empty. But is it not possible to have a set function $\mathfrak{h} \to \mathbb{C}$ that is a generalized eigenvector but is not linear; i.e., not an element of $\mathfrak{h}^*$?

It is not possible. If there exists some function $\lambda$ and some nonzero vector $v \in V_{\lambda}$ such that $\phi(h) v = \lambda(h) v$ for all $h$, then
$$\begin{eqnarray*} \phi(a h_1 + b h_2) v &=& \lambda(a h_1 + b h_2) v & \text{ by hypothesis} \\ 
 &=& (a \phi(h_1) + b \phi(h_2)) v & \text{ by linearity of } \phi \\
 &=& a \phi(h_1) v + b \phi(h_2) v & \text{ by linearity of the action} \\
 &=& a \lambda(h_1) v + b \lambda(h_2) v & \text{ by hypothesis} \\
 &=& (a \lambda(h_1) + b \lambda(h_2)) v & \text{ collecting terms}
 \end{eqnarray*}$$
so $\lambda$ must be linear, because $\phi$ is linear. This amounts to some very concrete statements about shared eigenvectors, e.g. that if $A, B$ are linear maps sharing an eigenvector $v$ with eigenvalues $\lambda_A, \lambda_B$ then $A + B$ shares the eigenvector $v$ with eigenvalue $\lambda_A + \lambda_B$, and similarly for scalar multiplication.
